# What is the plot function: number of galaxy-clusters ( gravitationally bound objects) within the cosmic event horizon vs. time?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, galaxy-clusters

I found this nice animation about the shrinking cosmic event horizon:http://yukterez.ist.org/lcdm/i.html#comoving

But now I am interested about the number of galaxy clusters (biggest gravitationally bound matter-objects). Does anyone know a discrete plot with estimates how the number of galaxy-clusters will shrink over time (till just one object "our local group" remains).